# Launch Adobe Acrobat Reader and media file simultaneously using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

On Windows 10, I would like to create a VBScript that launches Adobe Acrobat Reader in full-screen mode (to display a pdf), while simultaneously starting playback of a media file in the background. (The displayed file *must* be a pdf, so alternatives using PowerPoint or image files are not possible.) I have this script that does all of this but it gives me a pesky error despite all functionality. I tried to suppress the error message, but that made the whole thing crash. So, instead, I'm interested in solving the underlying error. Here's the script:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

acrobatPath = """C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"""
pdfFile = "C:\Users\X\Documents\Test.pdf"
command = acrobatPath & " " & pdfFile

objShell.Run command, 1, False

' Wait for Adobe Acrobat Reader to open
WScript.Sleep 1000

objShell.AppActivate("Adobe Acrobat")
WScript.Sleep 1000
' Open in full-screen mode
objShell.SendKeys("^l")

WScript.Sleep 1000 

' Start audio playback
Set objWMPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
objWMPlayer.settings.autoStart = True
objWMPlayer.settings.volume = 100
objWMPlayer.URL = "C:\Users\X\Documents\Test.wav"


Do While objAVDoc.GetAVDoc.GetView.ViewState = 1 ' 1 indicates that the PDF is open
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

The error I get is with the `objAVDoc` part, the error message says 'object required' (error code 800A01A8). (Note however, that despite the error, the script does what it is supposed to do, i.e. launches the presentation in full-screen mode and starts the playback.)

**EDIT:**
In the above code, the `objAVDoc` is not instantiated. To fix this, I defined the object, but this runs into another problem (error 800A01AD), which stops the execution of the script.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'path to pdf
pdfFile = "C:\Users\X\Documents\Test.pdf"
'path to sound file
soundFile = "C:\Users\X\Documents\Test.wav"

Set objAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroPDF.PDDoc")
Set objAVDoc.GetAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroPDF.AVDoc")

acrobatPath = """C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"""
command = acrobatPath & " " & pdfFile

objShell.Run command, 1, False

' Wait for Adobe Acrobat Reader to open
WScript.Sleep 1000

objShell.AppActivate("Adobe Acrobat")
WScript.Sleep 1000
' Open in full-screen mode
objShell.SendKeys("^l")

WScript.Sleep 1000 

' Start audio playback
Set objWMPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
objWMPlayer.settings.autoStart = True
objWMPlayer.settings.volume = 100
objWMPlayer.URL = soundFile

Do While objAVDoc.GetAVDoc.GetView.ViewState = 1 ' 1 indicates that the PDF is open
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

I also tried to create the `objAVDoc` object using

```
Set objAcroExch = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set objAVDoc = objAcroExch.GetActiveDoc
```

but that also does not work.

Any other approach that achieves the desired outcome (the simultaneous start of the pdf in full-screen mode and the playback of a sound in the background) is acceptable.

Comment: Does it have to be a PDF? If you can save your PDF as a JPG or PNG image, then the whole thing can be done as a simple 17 line HTA file. I'll post that as answer if you're interested.

Comment: At no point in the script is the `objAVDoc` object instantiated hence the error "Object Required".

Comment: The "Object Required" error is common in VBScript, there are numerous questions that cover this exact topic and the fact you have referenced variables that are not even instantiated in the script in the first place is where to start debugging what is wrong with the script.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to use PowerPoint, but glad to hear you solved it.

Comment: With due respect, may I ask why this question remains closed and flagged as "Not suitable for this site"? Based on the feedback, I edited the code and the description to clarify the desired behavior and the error and submitted it for review. However, after two weeks, the question remains closed.  I simply don't get it.  Clearly, the initial approach has some problems - this is why I asked the question. If the original were perfect, there would be no question. But I don't understand why this question is 'not suitable for this site'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to communicate with the Adobe Acrobat Reader, I used a different approach. I started both the Reader and then launched the media player. I also included a part that would stop the media playback in case the Acrobat Reader is no longer running. The following script does all of that:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Path to Adobe Acrobat Reader executable
acrobatPath = """C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"""
pdfFile = "C:\Users\X\Documents\Test.pdf"
command = acrobatPath & " /A ""pagemode=FullScreen"" " & pdfFile

' Start Adobe Acrobat Reader in full-screen mode with the specified PDF file
objShell.Run command, 1, False

' Wait for Adobe Acrobat Reader to open in full-screen mode
WScript.Sleep 1000

' Simulate Ctrl+L (full-screen mode hotkey)
objShell.AppActivate("Adobe Acrobat")
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys("^l")

' Start audio playback independently
Set objWMPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
objWMPlayer.settings.autoStart = True
objWMPlayer.settings.volume = 100
objWMPlayer.URL = "C:\Users\X\Documents\Test.wav"

' Allow time for both processes to initiate
WScript.Sleep(1000) ' Adjust the sleep duration as needed

' Monitor if Adobe Acrobat Reader is running
Do
    If Not IsProcessRunning("Acrobat.exe") Then
        ' Adobe Acrobat Reader is closed, so shut down media player
        objShell.Run "taskkill /f /im wmplayer.exe", 0, True
        Exit Do
    End If

    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

' Function to check if a process is running
Function IsProcessRunning(processName)
    Set colProcesses = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
    For Each objProcess In colProcesses
        If InStr(objProcess.Name, processName) > 0 Then
            IsProcessRunning = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsProcessRunning = False
End Function
```